# .NET Core - wireless file sending, WiFi Direct Device support?

Tags: c#, file-transfer, .net-core, wifi-direct, data-transfer

I was wanting to try write a little app (Win 10 UWP probably) using .NET core. I want to send a file between two computers/laptops through WiFi and learned about WiFi Direct and think I can use [this from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifidirect.wifidirectdevice.aspx).

How can I tell if .NET core supports this? If not, what would my options be?

As a bonus, if I use this can I open a socket and communicate the same as any traditional socket app?

Any other insight into .NET Core in this topic would be helpful.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to use just .Net Core, or UWP? What you linked to is a UWP class, so it will certainly work in UWP.

Comment: @svick This is my inexperience showing, hence the question. Maybe ignore the UWP, I am mainly interested in learning more about .NET Core, so I think basically what I am asking is how can I tell if something is supported in .NET Core? Specifically something with WiFi Direct.

Comment: @svick My understanding of the stack is limited, but I thought you could write UWP apps using .NET Core (but the features are more limited compared to .NET), like illustrated by [this picture](http://michalogluszka.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/dotnetcore.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# version of UWP is built on top of .Net Core. That is the only version of UWP, there is no UWP on top of .Net Framework, or anything like that.

That means that any UWP type will work in a UWP app.

But UWP is more than just .Net Core, so if you're interested in sharing code with other application types (.Net Core based ASP.NET Core and console applications or .Net Framework and Xamarin based applications), you will have to limit yourself to types from .Net Standard library (and libraries that built on top of them).

Comment: I think I understand, so WiFi Direct Device is part of UWP, so other things that use .NET Core won't have that class to use. How would I do that in .NET Core, if it isn't directly supported in .NET Core does that mean I would have to write it myself?

Comment: @lozzajp Yeah, I think so. There might be a way to use UWP types from a .Net Core console application, but it wouldn't be portable to e.g. Linux and it probably would be pretty complicated.